# ImportError: No module named test when ___init__.py is included

Tags: python

I created a python project in this format:

[image]

I tried to run my `test_jabba.py` by `cd`ing into the `tests` directory and running the program and I received this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_jabba.py", line 12, in <module>
    from tests import testbench
ImportError: No module named tests
```

I read around and I realized I needed `__init__.py` to tell python where other packages are located.

Top portion of `test_jabba.py`

```
from tests import testbench
from utils import gopher, jsonstream
```

I did not add `__init__.py` into my `logs` and `resources` directories as they do no contain any python.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be that `poc` is not in your `PYTHONPATH`. You can either set/extend the environment variable to contain `poc`, or 
[you can manipulate the path in your script using `os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html). Your imports, in this case, will have to change accordingly:

```
from poc.tests import testbench
from poc.utils import gopher, jsonstream
```

Alternatively, you can use a relative import, to import `tests` and `utils`:

```
from ..tests import testbench
from ..utils import gopher, jsonstream
```